# Jsoup html code parsing

Tags: android, parsing, jsoup

[This is an screenshot of site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oUjsB.jpg)

i am using following code

```
        @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            Connection.Response baglanilan = Jsoup.connect("http://www.eshot.gov.tr/tr/UlasimSaatleri/288")
                    .method(Connection.Method.GET)
                    .execute();
            Document document = Jsoup.connect("http://www.eshot.gov.tr/tr/UlasimSaatleri/288").data("hatId","581").cookies(baglanilan.cookies()).post();

                Elements bakiye = document.select("#frmDuraklar > ul > li");
                veri1ad = bakiye.toString();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        progressDialog.dismiss();
        tvveri.setText(veri1ad);
    }
```

code getting:

```
<li class="ring" id="10504">Fahrettin Altay</li>
<li class="ring" id="10507">İkinci Oyak Sitesi</li>
<li class="ring" id="10505">Ordu Pazarı</li>
<li class="ring" id="10506">Mehmet&ccedil;ik</li>
.
.
.
```

I need only id list from result. How can i parse just a id list?

Comment: what response "bakiye"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have almost near to output and forgot to iterate the elements

```
  try {
            Connection.Response baglanilan = Jsoup.connect("http://www.eshot.gov.tr/tr/UlasimSaatleri/288")
                    .method(Connection.Method.GET)
                    .execute();
            Document document = Jsoup.connect("http://www.eshot.gov.tr/tr/UlasimSaatleri/288").data("hatId","581").cookies(baglanilan.cookies()).post();


            Elements elements = document.select("#frmDuraklar > ul > li");

             for (Element element : elements) {
                 System.out.println(element.attr("id"));
             }



        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```